# match first column of file a with paragraphs of file b

Tags: text-processing

I have 2 files. The first, `fileA` looks like

```
TCONS_00000066  XLOC_000030     -       u       q1:XLOC_000030|TCONS_00000066|0|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|-
TCONS_00000130  XLOC_000057     -       u       q1:XLOC_000057|TCONS_00000130|0|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|-
TCONS_00000395  XLOC_000206     -       u       q1:XLOC_000204|TCONS_00000393|0|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|-
```

`FileB` looks like:

```
>TCONS_00000001 gene=XLOC_000001
AGATGAGCTGGTGGGGATGCTCTAAGAGAACGAGAGAAGCACAGAGCAGATAAACCACACCCACAGGCAC
CACCGTCCTTGTTGGTAATGAAGAAGACGAGACGACGACTTCCCCACTAGGAAACACGACGGAGGCGGAG
ATGATCGACGGCGGAGAGAGCTACAGAAACATCGATGCCTCCTGTCCAATCCCCCCATCCCATTCGGTAG
TTGGATTGAAGACTACCGAATAAGAGAAGCAGGCAGGCAGACAAACCCTTGAACCAAGGAGTCCTCGCTG
AGGAAGCTTTGGATCCACGACGCAGCTATGGCCTCCCCGCCCACCAGGCCGCCAGCCACAACCAGCTGAC
TAGGTCGCATGCATCATCAGATTTCAATCTCCCTTCGTTCCCTGTCCCTAATCCAATACCAATAGGGAGC
AATCAGCTGCTCCTCGACGGCGAGGGAGATGTCGTCGGCCGCGGGCCAAGACAACGGAGATACCGCTGGG
GACTACATCAAGTGGATGTGCGGCGCCGGTGGCCGTGCGGGCGGCGCCATGGCCAACCTCCAGCGCGGCG
TTGGCTCCCTCGTCCGTGACATTGGCGACCCCTGCCTCAACCCATCCCCCGTTAAGGGGAGCAAAATGCT
CAAACCGGAAAAATGGCACACATGTTTTGATAATGATGGAAAGGTCATAGGTTTCCGTAAAGCCCTAAAA
TTCATTGTCTTAGGGGGTGTGGATCCCACTATTCGAGCTGAAGTTTGGGAATTTCTTCTTGGCTGCTATG
CCTTGAGTAGTACCTCAGAGTATAGGAGGAAACTAAGAGCTGTTAGAAGGGAAAAATATCAAATTTTAGT
TAGACAGTGCCAGAGCATGCACCCAAGCATTGGTACAGGTGAGCTTGCTTACGCTGTTGGATCAAAGCTA
```

Now, `fileA` contains selected transcript numbers in the first column and `fileB` contains sequences of all transcripts. I want to scan `fileB` for the first column of `fileA` and print the trailing sequences of matching transcripts along with the transcript number.

Comment: So just to be clear: if `TCONS[^ ]*` in file a is also found at the head of a `[GTAC]*` block in b then that block should be printed - but not otherwise, right? It is a little confusing because if i understand you correctly then your example data does not produce a single desirable match.

Comment: yes u are correct. if TCON[]* from file a is found before any block in file b that is to be printed. all those into a third file mentioning the TCON * number ...here in this case starting from TCONS_00000066 XLOC_000030

Answer (score 3):

```sh
sed -n 's|^\(TCONS_[0-9]*\) .*|\
         /^>\1 /,/\\n>/P|p' fileA |
sed -e '$!N' -f - -e D fileB >outfile
```

...that should accomplish what you're after. For every line in fileA that begins with the string `TCONS_` and any digits followed by a space character the first `sed` will print a line like:

```
/^>TCONS_000001 /,/\n>/P
```

...where the `000001` is whatever the generating line's numeric sequence is.

The second `sed` is given three scripts - all of which it applies to its named input file - fileB.

1. The first is `$!N` which instructs it to append the `N`ext input line to pattern space for every line `!`but the `$`last.
2. The next is stdin - `-f -` - which the first `sed` constructs for it as noted.

   - Each line the first `sed` prints at the second is a 2-address range`//,//` instructing the second `sed` to `P`rint up to the first `\n`ewline in pattern space for every line falling between the two addresses.
3. The last script is just `D` which instructs `sed` to `D`elete up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space and try the three scripts again.

The result is that a match for any range the first `sed` scripts for the second begins when the block heading is at the `^`head of pattern space - an iteration after it is pulled in w/ `N`ext and the previous line is `D`eleted - and ends when the next block heading first appears and is still trailing pattern space as delimited by a `\n`ewline character. Because the second `sed` never `P`rints further than that delimiter, `sed` slides through fileB on a one-line lookahead - printing all blocks headed by strings found in column 1 of fileA and nothing else.

---

#### ANOTHER *(more complicated/efficient)* METHOD

---

Polished up:

```sh
also_fasta()( IFS='
';  get_match_lines(){
        tr   -s  '[:space:]'    \\n  |
        grep "$1" | grep -nFf - "$3"
    }
    get_script(){
        set \\ '\1,$p;n\' '1,\1b\1\' \
               '/^>/!b\1|p' '$c\' q
        sed -n "s|\([^:]*\).*|:\1$*"
    }
    get_match_lines "$@" < "$2"      |
    get_script | sed -nf - "$3"
)
```

If you define that function in your shell and call it like:

```
also_fasta 'TCONS_[0-9]*' fileA fileB
```

...it should do the trick.

I came up with that after doing some tests.  While the first definitely works, it is also definitely *slow* for large inputs.

After copying all of the `[ACGT]*` lines in your example to my clipboard, I created sample data like:

```sh
seq -w -s " gene=XLOC_dummy
$(        xsel -bo | sed 's/ *$//')
>TCONS_"  0 512 99999999 >/tmp/temp
```

The above uses `seq` to write blocks like:

```
>TCONS_99993600 gene=XLOC_dummy
AGATGAGCTGGTGGGGATGCTCTAAGAGAACGAGAGAAGCACAGAGCAGATAAACCACACCCACAGGCAC
CACCGTCCTTGTTGGTAATGAAGAAGACGAGACGACGACTTCCCCACTAGGAAACACGACGGAGGCGGAG
ATGATCGACGGCGGAGAGAGCTACAGAAACATCGATGCCTCCTGTCCAATCCCCCCATCCCATTCGGTAG
TTGGATTGAAGACTACCGAATAAGAGAAGCAGGCAGGCAGACAAACCCTTGAACCAAGGAGTCCTCGCTG
AGGAAGCTTTGGATCCACGACGCAGCTATGGCCTCCCCGCCCACCAGGCCGCCAGCCACAACCAGCTGAC
TAGGTCGCATGCATCATCAGATTTCAATCTCCCTTCGTTCCCTGTCCCTAATCCAATACCAATAGGGAGC
AATCAGCTGCTCCTCGACGGCGAGGGAGATGTCGTCGGCCGCGGGCCAAGACAACGGAGATACCGCTGGG
GACTACATCAAGTGGATGTGCGGCGCCGGTGGCCGTGCGGGCGGCGCCATGGCCAACCTCCAGCGCGGCG
TTGGCTCCCTCGTCCGTGACATTGGCGACCCCTGCCTCAACCCATCCCCCGTTAAGGGGAGCAAAATGCT
CAAACCGGAAAAATGGCACACATGTTTTGATAATGATGGAAAGGTCATAGGTTTCCGTAAAGCCCTAAAA
TTCATTGTCTTAGGGGGTGTGGATCCCACTATTCGAGCTGAAGTTTGGGAATTTCTTCTTGGCTGCTATG
CCTTGAGTAGTACCTCAGAGTATAGGAGGAAACTAAGAGCTGTTAGAAGGGAAAAATATCAAATTTTAGT
TAGACAGTGCCAGAGCATGCACCCAAGCATTGGTACAGGTGAGCTTGCTTACGCTGTTGGATCAAAGCTA
```

... to the file `/tmp/temp` where the numeric portion of the `>TCONS_[0-9]*` string is incremented from `00000512` through `99999999` at an interval of 512 per block. The whole file came to about 185mbs give or take.

I then did:

```sh
grep -F 00\  </tmp/temp | cut -d\> -f2 >/tmp/tempA
```

...for the pattern file *(which just narrows the selection to any `TCONS_[0-9]*00<space>` matches)*.

The line counts for both files were:

```sh
wc -l /tmp/temp*
  2734369 /tmp/temp
     7813 /tmp/tempA
  2742182 total
```

While I didn't run the two `sed`s against input of even that size - the largest I tried with the `sed | sed` suggestion was a data file a tithe of that size - and a pattern file selected on `2\` - which does come close to this, though.

Anyway, I thought about what was going on and I realized that with a pattern file approaching 8000 regexps then every time a line is `D`eleted it's got to work it's way back through checking all of those regexps that came before - over and over again. This is probably *not* optimally done.

At least in my generated input though I did have one thing going for me - it was more or less sequential. Following that thread I realized it didn't even have to be sequential if I could work by line number rather than regexp - so I turned to `grep`.

The command I ran *(and the basis for my function above)* is:

```sh
sed  -n 's|^\(TCONS_[0-9]*\) .*|>\1 |p
'    < /tmp/tempA              |
grep -nFf - /tmp/temp          |
sed  -n 's|\([^:]*\):.*|:\1\
        \1,$p;n;1,\1b\1\
        /^>/!b\1|p;$c\' -e q   |
sed  -nf - /tmp/temp
```

If you use this you should substitute in `fileB` for `/tmp/temp` and `fileA` for `/tmp/tempA`.

`grep -F` works with Fixed strings rather than regexp - and is far faster *(especially considering we're working w/ head-of-line matches)* - and the rest basically ignores all of `grep`'s results excepting the line numbers it returns at the head of each. The `sed` in the middle there massages `grep`'s output in such a way that the `sed` which winds up processing the data file proper will never backtrack its script even once - it will progress through its script file as it progresses through its input.

The `sed` in the middle writes something like the following at the last `sed` for every line `grep` prints:

```sh
:2732801                     #define branch label :LINENO
2732801,$p                   #if LINENO thru last line print
n                            #overwrite current line w/ next line
1,2732801b2732801            #if first line thru LINENO branch to :LINENO
/^>/!b2732801                #if !not /^>/ branch to :LINENO
```

So for every one of `grep`'s matches `sed` implements two tiny little read loops: the first is a noop in which `sed` overwrites the current line with the next until it has incremented the current line number to `grep`'s next match. The second is a print loop in which `sed` continually prints the current line then overwrites it with the next until a line matches `/^>/`. In this way `sed` processes its script in lockstep with its infile - never advancing any further in the script than the next matching line number will allow.

This outperforms the other script by several orders of magnitude. It processes the 185mbs like...

```sh
( also_fasta 'TCONS_[0-9]*' /tmp/tempA /tmp/temp; ) \
   3.93s user 0.39s system 100% cpu 4.281 total
```

...where the other handled input 10% of that size in...

```sh
( sed -n 's|^\(TCONS_[0-9]*\) .*|/>\1 /,/\\n>/P|p' /tmp/tempA  |sed -e  -f... ) \
108.58s user 0.04s system 100% cpu 1:48.56 total
```

More specifically, the line counts from the other script's input were:

```sh
wc -l /tmp/temp*
  273435 /tmp/temp
     782 /tmp/tempA
  274217 total
```

Comment: didnt get anything from above...how do you want me to proceed??

Comment: what does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to do this kind of thing often, I suggest you use a couple of tools I have<sup>1</sup> which are very useful for this sort of thing:

1. `FastaToTbl`:

   ```c
   #! /bin/sh
   gawk '{
           if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
           if (NR>1)
                       printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
           else 
               printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
           else 
                   printf "%s", $0
   }END{printf "\n"}'  "$@"
   ```

   Save that file as `FastaToTbl` in `~/bin` and make it executable with `chmod 755 ~/bin/FastaToTbl`.
2. `TblToFasta`

   ```c
   #! /bin/sh
   gawk '{
     sequence=$NF

     ls = length(sequence)
     is = 1
     fld  = 1

     while (fld < NF)
     {
        if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
        printf "%s " , $fld
         if (fld == NF-1)
         {
           printf "\n"
         }
         fld = fld+1
     }
      while (is <= ls)
     {
       printf "%s\n", substr(sequence,is,60)
       is=is+60
     }
   }' "$@"
   ```

   Save that file as `TblToFasta` in `~/bin` and make it executable with `chmod 755 ~/bin/TblToFasta`.

Now that you have those two scripts set up, you can use `FastaToTbl` to change your FASTA sequences to Tbl format (Sequence name, TAB, sequence) which is far easier to search through:

```
FastaToTbl fileB | grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' fileA)  | TblToFasta
```

That uses the `FastaToTbl` script to put sequence and ID on the same file. The `awk '{print $1}' fileA` prints the 1st field of `fileA` and, because we're using `<()` this can be passed as a "file" to grep's `-f` option which asks for a file of patterns to search for. Finally, `TblToFasta` returns the FASTA format.

---

Finally, you might want to check out my [`retrieveseqs.pl`](https://github.com/terdon/scripts/blob/master/retrieveseqs.pl) script which can do this and many other things. For example, in this case, you could have just done:

```
retrieveseqs.pl -f fileB fileA
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Thanks to J.F. Abril who originally wrote these two scripts.</sub>

Comment: nothing working for me..:(. just getting the fileB with all sequences again and again.

Comment: @dinesh sorry, the awk script was wrong, my bad. I replaced it with a different approach. However, if you work with sequences often, I recommend you use one of the other two, more sophisticated solutions.

Comment: I think you can make each of those scripts just a little more efficient by dropping `sh` altogether. They should work, I think, with `#!/path/to/gawk` bang-lines - in which case you can drop everything outside the `''` layer. If you do that the kernel will just pass `"$@"` to `gawk` automatically. If the `/bin/gawk` pathing is uncertain you can use `/bin/env - gawk` instead - which is a little more likely to resolve on any machine and is very likely still way cheaper than getting a whole shell to call it up. Another advantage is that you'll free up single-quotes to use in-script.

Comment: @terdon...where is the perl script you wrote. it worked like miracle!!!! thank you for that..

Comment: @mikeserv....thank you for the follow through. i will try it

Comment: @dinesh you're welcome but if one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.