# filter out length

Tags: grep

I have a file which contains 3940 sequences and looks like

```
>TCONS_00000066 gene=XLOC_000030
CCGCCGGCTGCTGCGCGCACCGACTTGTCACCACCCCAGCACGTCCTCCACGTATACAAG
CGCTACGGTCCACCGCGGCAGCGTCGACGTCCTTGTCCGCAAACATGGTGGTGGCAGCTT
CCTCATCGAGCAGCAGCAACTCATCCTCGAGGGGAAGGGCCCAGAGCTTCTAATCCTACA
CGGCAACAACACTTTATACTTGTGTATAATTTCTCTTCGTTTCTGAGTTCATGGCTATCT
TTGTCTCTCTTATCTTCTCCCTTTTGCTATCTCTATATTTGTGATTGCCATGGAAATACA
>TCONS_00006042 gene=XLOC_003448
GCCACTAGCCAGCCCAGCCAGGGGAAGGGGAGGAGCTGCAAGCCCAACCCCCTGCTCAAC
CCTAAATTGCTTCCGCCGATCGGTGAGAGCTCCGATGCCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTC
CCCCTCTACCTGTTCCTTCTCCGAGATAACTGCAACATTTTCAGCACTTTTTCTGGCCAT
TCTCAAGTCCCCAGCCCAGGGACTAGAGTGTTACTATGGCTAGAGCAAATGAGATGGTCA
GGGCAGACTCAAGGATGATGGTTGTCTTTAGTGCCCTGGCATCTAAATCAGGGCCACTGA
CATTTGAAGACTCGCTCAGATTTGTCAAGAAAGTGAAGGCTTGTAACTACATGTTGTATT
```

I want the sequences which are longer than 200 characters in another file

Comment: "in another file" meaning you don't want them left in the input? Or do you want them in another file as well as in this file?

Comment: sequence > 200, do you mean linelength or all the data (except newlines?) between 2 >TCON tags?

Comment: yes all data. not line length. all data between 2 >TCONS tags

Comment: @WALTER A: count all data between 2>TCON tags and filter out those greater than 200 in length

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed or awk or grep.

```
awk 'length($0)>200' file > newfile
```

OR

```
grep '^.\{201\}' file > newfile
```

Comment: i think he wants to copy the lines which has the length more than 200 to another file.

Comment: not working. gerating blank files

Comment: is there any output produced after running `awk 'length($0)>200' file` command?

Comment: not single lines. staring from ">TCONS*" but reading from GGATG*. it will read from ATA* of every ">TCONS*" and print those which are >=200 in lenght to other file

Comment: no awk 'length($0)>200' file produced a blank file

Comment: it reads from the top and print only the lines which has the characters of minimum 200. `no awk 'length($0)>200' file produced a blank file`, because no one line on your input file has min 200 chars.

Comment: @user106326 how you calculate 200 chars? block by block?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you need to set `>` as a record separator first:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";ORS=""}length($0)>200{print ">"$0}' input > output
```

Another option with `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M '^>[^>]{201,}' input > output
```

Or to count only DNA sequences, not characters in header:

```
pcregrep -M '^>[^>]*\n[^>]{201,}' input > output
```

Comment: again blank file generated

Comment: @user106326 Impossible, is your file exactly in the format you show here? Anyway see the edit and try with `pcregrep`.

Comment: oh sorry. it worked but its still not showing the required amount i wanted to see. from a previous perl script i got 3817 count. here i got 3873

Comment: @user106326 I see, the problem is that it counts characters in whole blocks, while it should only gen sequence, excluding header. Try `pcregrep -M '^>[^>]*\n[^>]{201,}' file`

Comment: now its correct. i got 3817....thanks a lot

Comment: again 3889 counts..:(

Comment: @user106326 correct, not correct... what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Python (`split.py`):

```
import sys

# call with the file as parameter

base = 0
line = ''
with open(sys.argv[-1]) as fp:
    with open('shorter', 'w') as fps:
        with open('longer', 'w') as fpl:
            for x in fp:
                if line and x.startswith('>'):
                    print len(line), base
                    if (len(line) - base) >= 200:
                        fpl.write(line)
                    else:
                        fps.write(line)
                    line = x
                    base = len(x)  # lenght of the ">..." line
                    continue
                if x.startswith('>'):  # very first one
                    base = len(x)
                line += x
            if line:
                if len(line) >= 200:
                    fpl.write(line)
                else:
                    fps.write(line)
                line = ""
```

call with `python split.py inputfile` and then `mv shorter inputfile` (after checking that the files are OK)

Comment: File "filterlength.py", line 2
    with open('shorter', 'w') as fps:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @user106326 There was a space too many at the beginning of each line

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split.py", line 8, in <module>
    fps.stdout.write(x)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'stdout'

Comment: @user106326 I think the update better does what you need. it takes the length of the accumulated sequence (keeping into account the `>......` which doesn't count against the 200)

Comment: the shorter file is same as input while longer file is blank

Comment: i want sequences longer than 200 . why move shoter into input??

Comment: Copy and paste your example to `inputfile`, makes sure that if you do `wc inputfile` you actually have 13 lines. That input gives two sequences in longer. Does your input file have newlines breaking up the sequences?

Comment: @user106326 you asked "want [..] in another file" not "want [...] in another file as well" because of that you indicate you want to remove from the input. If that is not what you want update your question (I asked that 3 hours ago in a comment to your question).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
f=0
for arg in -e -v
do  f=$((f+1))
    tr '>\n' '\n>' <infile |
    grep "$arg" '>.\{200\}'|
    tr '>\n' '\n>' >"./outfile$f"
done
```

Which will write all sequences 200 chars or longer to outfile1 and all those shorter to outfile2.

It translates all `>` to `\n`ewlines and vice-versa - so your first example above becomes:

```
TCONS_00000066 gene=XLOC_000030>CCGCCGGCTGCTGCGCGCACCGACTTGTCACCACCCCAGCACGTCCTCCACGTATACAAG>CGCTACGGTCCACCGCGGCAGCGTCGACGTCCTTGTCCGCAAACATGGTGGTGGCAGCTT>CCTCATCGAGCAGCAGCAACTCATCCTCGAGGGGAAGGGCCCAGAGCTTCTAATCCTACA>CGGCAACAACACTTTATACTTGTGTATAATTTCTCTTCGTTTCTGAGTTCATGGCTATCT>TTGTCTCTCTTATCTTCTCCCTTTTGCTATCTCTATATTTGTGATTGCCATGGAAATACA>
```

It then matches *(or doesn't)* 200 chars from the first occurring `>` for each input line. For the first iteration of the `for` loop - the one which matches lines with 200 chars or more - it reverses the translation for the lines which `grep` matches and writes the results to outfile1. The second iteration gets shorter sequences and writes them to outfile2.

You should note that this count will include any newlines that were in the data.

Here's another way that doesn't have that problem:

```
sed -n '/^>/!{H;$!d
};   x;s/\n[ACGT]\{20\}/&/4p
'    <infile >outfile
```

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: @user106326 - you should try it again - you must have typed something wrong. There was no syntax error - though the iterator `$f` was staying at 0 because it was behind a pipe. Still, that would only get the `outfile0` file written twice is all.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | while read -r line; do
  if [ ${#line} -gt 200 ]; then
    echo "${line}"
  fi
done
```

EDIT
Question has been updated: not the length of one line but a set of lines is wanted.

In the following script I echo >TCONS otherwise the script will skip the last hit.

```
multiline=""
(cat input; echo ">TCONS string for last token") | while read line; do
        if [[ "$(echo "${line}"| cut -c1-6)" = ">TCONS" ]]; then
                if [ ${#multiline} -gt 200 ]; then
                        echo "${multiline}"
                fi
                multiline=""
        else
                multiline="${multiline}${line}"
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I already gave you my `FastaToTbl` and `TblToFasta` scripts in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189740/22222). Using them, you could do

```
FastaToTbl sequences.fa | awk 'length($2)>200' | TblToFasta > newfile.fa
```

---

#### FastaToTbl

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
        if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
        if (NR>1)
                    printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
            printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
                printf "%s", $0
}END{printf "\n"}
```

#### TblToFasta

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
{
  sequence=$NF

  ls = length(sequence)
  is = 1
  fld  = 1
  while (fld < NF)
  {
     if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
     printf "%s " , $fld

     if (fld == NF-1)
      {
        printf "\n"
      }
      fld = fld+1
  }
  while (is <= ls)
  {
    printf "%s\n", substr(sequence,is,60)
    is=is+60
  }
}
```